# Adding Highcharter bubble size legend in R

Tags: r, highcharts, legend, legend-properties, r-highcharter

Trying to figure it out, if highcharter allows to display bubbles by size on a legend.

Data looks like

```
> dput(unbanked)
structure(list(country = c("DZ", "BJ", "BW", "BF", "CM", "CF", 
"TD", "CD", "CG", "CI", "ET", "GA", "GH", "GN", "KE", "LS", "LR", 
"MG", "MW", "ML", "MR", "MA", "MZ", NA, "NE", "NG", "RW", "SN", 
"SL", "ZA", "SS", "TZ", "TG", "TN", "UG", "ZM", "ZW"), lat = c(28.033886, 
9.30769, -22.328474, 12.238333, 7.369722, 6.611111, 15.454166, 
-4.038333, -0.228021, 7.539989, 9.145, -0.803689, 7.946527, 9.945587, 
-0.023559, -29.609988, 6.428055, -18.766947, -13.254308, 17.570692, 
21.00789, 31.791702, -18.665695, -22.95764, 17.607789, 9.081999, 
-1.940278, 14.497401, 8.460555, -30.559482, 4.8472, -6.369028, 
8.619543, 33.886917, 1.373333, -13.133897, -19.015438), lon = c(1.659626, 
2.315834, 24.684866, -1.561593, 12.354722, 20.939444, 18.732207, 
21.758664, 15.827659, -5.54708, 40.489673, 11.609444, -1.023194, 
-9.696645, 37.906193, 28.233608, -9.429499, 46.869107, 34.301525, 
-3.996166, -10.940835, -7.09262, 35.529562, 18.49041, 8.081666, 
8.675277, 29.873888, -14.452362, -11.779889, 22.937506, 31.59, 
34.888822, 0.824782, 9.537499, 32.290275, 27.849332, 29.154857
), name = c("Algeria", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Cameroon", 
"Central African Republic", "Chad", "Congo, Dem. Rep", "Congo, Brazzaville", 
"Cote d'Ivoire", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Kenya", 
"Lesotho", "Liberia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", 
"Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", 
"Senegal", "Sierra Leone", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Tanzania", 
"Togo", "Tunisia", "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), z = c(0.88, 
1.37, 0.17, 2.1, 2.93, 0.52, 0.86, 3.77, 0.36, 2.1, 19.38, 0.22, 
1.81, 1.08, 4.7, 0.14, 0.91, 0.44, 2.54, 2.15, 0.37, 1, 1.91, 
0.06, 0.72, 23.57, 2.38, 1.6, 1.27, 8.4, 0.81, 3.4, 0.71, 0.2, 
5.21, 1.05, 1.47)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -37L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), lat = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), lon = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), z = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Desired output is [image]

Current status is here [image]

@JBKunst [replied](https://twitter.com/jbkunst/status/1093882901593247744) to me on Twitter, it is definitely [possible](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/bubble-legend) with Highcharts, but how to add it, if you are not .js person?

My code is

```
hcmap("custom/africa") %>%
hc_add_series(data = data, type = "mapbubble", 
maxSize = '10%', color = "Red",
name = "Name", showInLegend = FALSE) %>% 
hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
```

Thanks!

**UPD**

I added

```
hc_legend(enabled = TRUE, layout = "vertical", 
align = "right", bubbleLegend =  list(enabled = TRUE))
```

but it is definitely far from being perfect. Ideally I need 3 bubbles - min, mid, max value.

**UPD2**
The author of the package created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10101) after my problem

[image]

Comment: Could you share your `data` object? You can paste the output of `dput(data)` in your question.

Comment: @MarcoSandri, added, thanks for looking into it